# Syntax error on token "}", { expected

Tags: java

This problem is persisting. I cannot remove it. Please help!
I have tried many different things but nothing is working.

```
package me.swoq;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;

import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import java.util.Random;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.permissions.Permission;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.Material;


public class RTPPlus extends JavaPlugin {

    public Permission playerPermission = new Permission("rtp.teleport");

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("rtp") && sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;                
        Location originalLocation = player.getLocation();
        Random random = new Random();

        int x = random.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        int y = 70;
        int z = random.nextInt(1000) + 1;

        boolean isOnLand = false;

        while (isOnLand == false) {

        Location teleportLocation = new Location(player.getWorld(), x, y, z);

        if (teleportLocation.getBlock().getType() != Material.AIR) {
             isOnLand = true;



        player.teleport(teleportLocation);

        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been teleported " + (int)teleportLocation.distance(originalLocation) + " blocks away!");




        }

        return true;

        }

    } 
    return false;       
    }
    return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Correctly indenting your code may provide you with the solution, or if you use an IDE, such as Eclipse, it will point out syntax errors for you.

Comment: Yeah, if you are going to ask for help on a syntax error regarding brackets, you can't expect people to help unless you indent your code correctly.

Comment: Flagged to close as **off-topic | simple typographical error**.

Comment: FYI: Once you fix the syntax error you're going to run into a logical error. The first iteration of your while loop will always return true. In other words, your while loop will only loop once and your method will always return true, if the first if statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last 2 `return false` statements and check with your method's scope.

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    //method content
    }
    return false;       
}
return false;
}
```

You have an additional return statement after closing the method's curly braces. Please format your code, then you will see what has gone wrong.

Remove the last `return false` and closing curly brace `("}")`